# glob to match all files except top-level vendor or any-depth node_modules

Tags: node.js, glob, stylelint

I'm trying to write a [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) to match `.css` or `.scss` files but ignore `vendor` and ignore `node_modules` at any nesting depth.

```
vendor/please-ignore.css
vendor/example/please-ignore.css
node_modules/any/please-ignore.css
other/please-match.css
other/example/please-match.css
other/node_modules/please-ignore.css
other/example/node_modules/please-ignore.css
another/please-match.css
another/example/please-match.css
another/node_modules/please-ignore.css
another/example/node_modules/please-ignore.css
```

I feel like I'm close. This successfully ignores top-level `vendor` and `node_modules` but still matches nested `node_modules`:

```
stylelint './!(vendor|node_modules)/**/*.?(s)css'
```

How can I adjust to blacklist `node_modules` at any level?

Answer (score 2):

Try `stylelint '**/!(vendor|node_modules)/*.?(s)css'`

This should ignore `vendor` and `node_modules` at *any nesting depth*, including the top level.